# Why does this simple transaction deadlock with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I'm encountering intermittent deadlocks in the following proc:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_set_user_password (IN user_id INT, IN algorithm INT, IN hash VARBINARY(256))
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        RESIGNAL;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;
        UPDATE `UserPassword` SET `Active` = 0 WHERE `UserId` = user_id;
        INSERT INTO `UserPassword` (`UserId`, `Active`, `Algorithm`, `Hash`) VALUES (user_id, 1, algorithm, hash);
COMMIT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This table has a composite index on `UserId` and `Active` (`IX_UserPassword_UserId_Active`).

Someone tried to run a load test that created many users in parallel, and they encountered the deadlock very consistently. Looking at the logs, I see that the deadlock occurs when this proc runs with adjacent `user_id` values.

I'm really looking for a real explanation of **why** this results in a deadlock. I've had various mixed and conflicting answers, none of which make sense, ranging from *because one transaction has the lock and the other lock can't acquire it (even though there's only one lock in question)* to *that's just how MySQL works, deal with it*.

See an example of the deadlock below:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2016-08-26 00:21:52 2b30caecc700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 71925393848, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 4901, OS thread handle 0x2b30cc1d7700, query id 37117819 <server> update
INSERT INTO `UserPassword` (`UserId`, `Active`, `Algorithm`, `Hash`) VALUES ( NAME_CONST('user_id',72332427), 1,  NAME_CONST('algorithm',2),  NAME_CONST('hash',_binary'<data>' COLLATE 'binary'))
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 388 page no 117300 n bits 784 index `IX_UserPassword_UserId_Active` of table `users`.`UserPassword` trx id 71925393848 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 714 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 844fb48c; asc  O  ;;
 1: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 2: len 4; hex 818106f9; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 71925393846, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
6 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 4909, OS thread handle 0x2b30caecc700, query id 37117815 <server> update
INSERT INTO `UserPassword` (`UserId`, `Active`, `Algorithm`, `Hash`) VALUES ( NAME_CONST('user_id',72332426), 1,  NAME_CONST('algorithm',2),  NAME_CONST('hash',_binary'<data>' COLLATE 'binary'))
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 388 page no 117300 n bits 784 index `IX_UserPassword_UserId_Active` of table `users`.`UserPassword` trx id 71925393846 lock_mode X locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 714 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 844fb48c; asc  O  ;;
 1: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 2: len 4; hex 818106f9; asc     ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 388 page no 117300 n bits 784 index `IX_UserPassword_UserId_Active` of table `users`.`UserPassword` trx id 71925393846 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 714 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 844fb48c; asc  O  ;;
 1: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 2: len 4; hex 818106f9; asc     ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156875/why-does-this-simple-update-and-insert-transaction-deadlock-with-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's an illustration on how gap locks work -http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks  .

Say you have adjacent user id , 1 and 2.  When procedure executed simultaneously from 2 different sessions, each of them put a gap lock on two index-records (with user_id values 1 and 2 - maybe 0 ,4,5 as well ,but let's assume just 2 for simplicity sake), and each of them has to wait for another one to release the lock to perform an insert.

> Gap locks in InnoDB are “purely inhibitive”, which means they only
>   stop other transactions from inserting to the gap. They do not prevent
>   different transactions from taking gap locks on the same gap. Thus, a
>   gap X-lock has the same effect as a gap S-lock *."

To disable locks,

> Gap locking can be disabled explicitly. This occurs if you change the
>   transaction isolation level to READ COMMITTED or enable the
>   innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog system variable (which is now
>   deprecated). Under these circumstances, gap locking is disabled for
>   searches and index scans and is used only for foreign-key constraint
>   checking and duplicate-key checking.

Using `READ COMMITTED` sounds like a reasonable solution to me, assuming it doesn't break application logic.